# How do I modify the position property of textItems in Keynote using JavaScript for applications?

Tags: javascript, keynote

```
var Keynote = new Application("Keynote")
var itemPosition = Keynote.documents[0].slides[1].textItems[2].position
```

*get the itemPosition coordinates
Keynote.documents[0].slides[1].textItems[2].position()*

```
Keynote.documents[0].slides[1].textItems[2].position()
```

*the result is below*

```
app = Application("Keynote")
app.documents.at(0).slides.at(1).textItems.at(1).position = {"x":0, "y":0}
```

*create the variable with new properties position*

```
var newPositionItem = [150, 400]
```

*apply the value to the element with asignment*

```
Keynote.documents[0].slides[1].textItems[1].position = newPositionItem
```

*Result: nothing changes...*

Answer (score 0):

try using .setLeft() for Horizontal position, and .setTop() for vertical position on the text item.

```js
var textItem = slide.textItems()[0];

// Sets the horizontal position 100 pixels from the left edge of the slide
textItem.setLeft(100);

// Set the vertical position 200 pixels from the top edge of the slide
textItem.setTop(200);
```

Comment: I solved the problem: I had to pass a dictionary! and not an array as a value. I really appreciated your help ❤️